# How to continuously execute an async function not in parallel with only the latest from the stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I've been stuck with a rxjs problem for days now. I use rxjs with REACT and trying to get to a stream of property changes to run an asynchronous function to fast-forward / rewind a player. Then to further await any function calls until the callback returns. If any property changes happened in the stream while waiting for the callback just execute the last of it. To then repeat the process.

Here is an example code below.
http://jsbin.com/jagoworawu/edit?js,console

```js
const setCurrentTimeStream = Observable.bindNodeCallback(player.setCurrentTime);

// Instant execute setCurrentTimeStream on first iteration.
// Prevent next setCurrentTimeStream if not callback of previous setCurrentTimeStream was called.
// Skip all except last while waiting for setCurrentTimeStream callback and then execute it.
// Then repeat the process.
const lifecycle$ = props$
  .distinctUntilKeyChanged('currentTime')
  // tried with audit and throttle but it won't execute the last one
  .audit(({ currentTime }) => setCurrentTimeStream(currentTime));
  // Probably needs something more here?
```

**EDIT**:
After reading some documentation I came up with this. Please come with feedback or other solution preferably with native method from rxjs.

```js
const latestExecAsync = (input, action) => Observable.create((observer) => {
  let queued = false;
  let latestValue;
  const dequeue = (reference) => {
    queued = true;
    action(reference.value, (error, value) => {
      if (error) return output.error(error);
      observer.next(reference.value);
      if (reference !== latestValue) {
        dequeue(latestValue);
      } else {
        queued = false;
      }
    });
  };
  const subscription = input.subscribe({
    next: (value) => {
      const reference = latestValue = { value };
      if (!queued) dequeue(reference);
    },
    error: e => observer.error(e),
    complete: () => observer.complete(),
  });
  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
});

// Usage:
latestExecAync(
  props$.distinctUntilKeyChanged('currentTime'),
  ({ currentTime }, cb) => player.setCurrentTime(currentTime, cb)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with the with the behavior I was looking for. Using only rxjs native methods. :)

```js
const currentTime$ = props$.pluck('currentTime');
const $trailingCurrentTime = new Subject();

const stream$ = Observable
  .merge(currentTime$, $trailingCurrentTime)
  .audit(currentTime => setCurrentTime$(currentTime))
  .filter(currentTime => {
    if (currentTime !== player.currentTime) {
      $trailingCurrentTime.next(currentTime);
    }
    return currentTime === player.currentTime;
  });
```

http://jsbin.com/wedefojuyo/edit?js,console,output